# How do I use youtube-ios-player-helper in a SwiftUI project?

Tags: swiftui, youtube

I'm trying to use youtube videos on my test app, and I found youtube-ios-player-helper. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any example of using it with SwiftUI. Could anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `YTPlayerView` is a `UIView`, you'll need to wrap it in UIViewRepresentable to use it in SwiftUI:

```
import YouTubeiOSPlayerHelper

struct YTWrapper : UIViewRepresentable {
    var videoID : String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> YTPlayerView {
        let playerView = YTPlayerView()
        playerView.load(withVideoId: videoID)
        return playerView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: YTPlayerView, context: Context) {
        //
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        YTWrapper(videoID: "jQtP1dD6jQ0")
    }
}
```

Note that you may need to make different decisions about where to load the video (`makeUIView` vs `updateUIView`) depending on your needs.

Comment: Can you please explain how I can add buttons to the player itself?
For example, the button that dismisses the screen in the current Youtube app from the AppStore

Comment: @jnpdx I need to call the delegate method of YTPlayerView in SwiftUI. I need to redirect the screen on video finish.

Comment: @Birendra sounds like a good opportunity to create a new question for that